# Splitting string to object in JS

Tags: javascript

I get a response from a server like this:

```
3S1,https://lekcjaplus.vulcan.net.pl
TA1,https://uonetplus-komunikacja.umt.tarnow.pl
OP1,https://uonetplus-komunikacja.eszkola.opolskie.pl
RZ1,https://uonetplus-komunikacja.resman.pl
GD1,https://uonetplus-komunikacja.edu.gdansk.pl
P03,https://efeb-komunikacja-pro-efebmobile.pro.vulcan.pl
P01,http://efeb-komunikacja.pro-hudson.win.vulcan.pl
P02,http://efeb-komunikacja.pro-hudsonrc.win.vulcan.pl
P90,http://efeb-komunikacja-pro-mwujakowska.neo.win.vulcan.pl
```

I want to convert it to an object like this:

```
"3S1": "https://lekcjaplus.vulcan.net.pl",
"TA1": "https://uonetplus-komunikacja.umt.tarnow.pl",
"OP1": "https://uonetplus-komunikacja.eszkola.opolskie.pl",
"RZ1": "https://uonetplus-komunikacja.resman.pl",
"GD1": "https://uonetplus-komunikacja.edu.gdansk.pl",
"P03": "https://efeb-komunikacja-pro-efebmobile.pro.vulcan.pl",
"P01": "http://efeb-komunikacja.pro-hudson.win.vulcan.pl",
"P02": "http://efeb-komunikacja.pro-hudsonrc.win.vulcan.pl",
"P90": "http://efeb-komunikacja-pro-mwujakowska.neo.win.vulcan.pl"
```

What's the simplest way to achieve this?

Comment: Is the top one a single string or a series of strings?

Comment: do you get an array of strings or one of line in top???

Comment: It's simply one, multi-line string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `split` by new line and use `reduce`

```js
let str = `3S1,https://lekcjaplus.vulcan.net.pl
 TA1,https://uonetplus-komunikacja.umt.tarnow.pl
 OP1,https://uonetplus-komunikacja.eszkola.opolskie.pl
 RZ1,https://uonetplus-komunikacja.resman.pl
 GD1,https://uonetplus-komunikacja.edu.gdansk.pl
 P03,https://efeb-komunikacja-pro-efebmobile.pro.vulcan.pl
 P01,http://efeb-komunikacja.pro-hudson.win.vulcan.pl
 P02,http://efeb-komunikacja.pro-hudsonrc.win.vulcan.pl
 P90,http://efeb-komunikacja-pro-mwujakowska.neo.win.vulcan.pl`;

let result = str.split(/\n/).reduce((c, v) => {
  if( v.trim() !== '' ) {
       let [k, o] = v.trim().split(',');
       c[k] = o;
  }
  return c;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

In case you have multiple `,` on each line, you can deconstruct the array and `join(',')`

```
let result = str.split(/\n/).reduce((c,v)=>{
    if( v.trim() ) {
        let [k,...o] = v.trim().split(',');
        c[k] = o.join(',');
    }
    return c;
},{});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to split the string into lines

Then split every line into two parts, the first part will be a key and the second one will be the value of the same key.

```js
let input = `3S1,https://lekcjaplus.vulcan.net.pl
TA1,https://uonetplus-komunikacja.umt.tarnow.pl
OP1,https://uonetplus-komunikacja.eszkola.opolskie.pl
RZ1,https://uonetplus-komunikacja.resman.pl
GD1,https://uonetplus-komunikacja.edu.gdansk.pl
P03,https://efeb-komunikacja-pro-efebmobile.pro.vulcan.pl
P01,http://efeb-komunikacja.pro-hudson.win.vulcan.pl
P02,http://efeb-komunikacja.pro-hudsonrc.win.vulcan.pl
P90,http://efeb-komunikacja-pro-mwujakowska.neo.win.vulcan.pl`;


output = input.split(/\n/g);

output = output.reduce((acc, item) => {
    item = item.split(",");
    acc[item[0]] = item[1];
    return acc;
}, {})

console.log(output);
```